# What's the best way to see if someone is still using the app?

Tags: react-native, mobile

Here's the problem: I have a React-Native/Redux app. I need to make sure I can lock the screen (display a modal, really) after X minutes of app inactivity (theoretically someone may have their screen "always on", so I can't rely on the screen turning itself off).

My proposed solution: I want to detect when *any* touch event happens. I don't want to interfere with them or do anything about it other than reset a `setTimeout`. But I just want to know when the screen is touched at all.

Displaying the modal itself isn't an issue and is already working. I also have it display the modal if the app leaves the foreground for any reason. I just need the timeout.

I've tried using a TouchableWthoutFeedback that wraps the whole UI and that sorta works, but it doesn't receive any event when a Touchable is farther down the component tree and handles the event. But I've also only used `onPressIn` and I'm unsure if anything else on it will work as needed. I've looked briefly at `PanResponder` but that looks a bit more complex than I might need? Not sure on that one, yet.

I'm open to other suggestions, but the only other thing I can think of is having literally every other action in the app (even ones I haven't created yet) send an dispatch up the redux flagpole, and that seems very heavy-handed and prone to error.

is this feasible? What are my options if it's not?

Comment: Is it required to detect inactivity, instead of just device lock? Device lock can be accomplished with the AppState module.

Comment: Yes, it's a requirement. I'm already detecting AppState changes and that works fine. I just need a screen activity timeout separate from the built-in-screen lock. In case someone has the screen set to "Always On".

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It's to add a `onStartShouldSetResponderCapture` callback as a prop on a containing View. I can return false in this callback but still notice all the touch events that come through. The `Capture` portion is important because it gives you access to the event before a "real" touchable can get to it.

Then, in the callback, I just clear and re-create the timer.